# Trying to add links to react Navbar to other pages of my app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tailwind-css

Have created a Sidenav and im looking to enable the buttons to link to their respective pages within the app.

Ive tried adding Src option to the Const menu item however im struggling to define them to each different button

any help would be appreciated reasonable new to react

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { 
AiFillFolder,
AiFillHome,
AiOutlineCloudServer,
AiFillFire,
AiOutlineLogout,
AiFillSetting,
AiFillSave
 } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsFillPersonFill, BsArrowLeftShort, BsSearch, BsChevronDown } from "react-icons/bs";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Sidebarnav = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [submenuOpen, setSubmenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const Menus = [
        { title: "Home",},
        { title: "Trending", icon: <AiFillFire />},
        { title: "Servers", icon: <AiOutlineCloudServer />},
        { 
            title: "Mods",
            icon: <AiFillSave />,
            submenu: true,
            submenuItems: [
                { title: "GTA Mods" },
                { title: "RedDead Mods" },
                { title: "Skyrim Mods" },
            ],       
    },
    { title: "Uploads", icon: <AiFillFolder />},
    { title: "Settings", icon: <AiFillSetting />},
    { title: "Logout", icon: <AiOutlineLogout />}
    ];
  return (
    <div className={`bg-blue-500 border border-black h-screen p-5 pt-8 relative z-[1000px] ${open 
    } duration-300 relative`}>

      <BsArrowLeftShort className={`bg-white text-black rounded-full absolute text-3xl -right-4     
       border-black cursor-pointer
       ${!open && "rotate-180"}`} 
      onClick={() => setOpen (!open)} />

      <div className='inline-flex'>
        <BsFillPersonFill className={`bg-white text-4xl rounded w-[40px] cursor-pointer block 
        ${open && "rotate-[360deg]"}`} />
        <h1 className={`text-white text-center origin-left font-medium text-2xl duration-300 
        UserName
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div className={`flex items-center rounded-md bg-black mt-6 
      ${!open ? "px-2.5" : "px-4" } py-2`}
      >
        <BsSearch
         className={`text-white text-lg block float-left 
         cursor-pointer 
         ${open && "mr-2"}`} 
         />

        <input 
        type={"search"} 
        placeholder="Search" 
        className={`text-base bg-transparent w-full text-white 
        focus:outline-none 
        ${!open && "hidden"
        }`}  
        />
      </div>
        <ul className='"pt-2'>
            {Menus.map((menu , index) => (
            <>
            <li 
            key={index} 
            className={`text-gray-300 text-sm flex 
            items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2
             hover:bg-black rounded-md ${menu.spacing ? "mt-9" : "mt-2"}`} 
             >
        
             <span className='text-2xl block float-left'> 
                 {menu.icon ? menu.icon : <AiFillHome />} 
             </span>
             <span className={`text-base font-medium flex-1 
             ${!open && "hidden"}`}
             >
             {menu.title}
             </span>
             {menu.submenu && open && (
                <BsChevronDown className={`${submenuOpen && "rotate-180"}`} onClick={()=> 
                setSubmenuOpen(!submenuOpen)} />
             )}
            </li>
            {menu.submenu && submenuOpen && open && (
                <ul>
                    {menu.submenuItems.map((submenuItem, index) => (
                    <li key={index} className="text-gray-300 text-sm flex 
                    items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 px-5
                     hover:bg-black rounded-md">
                        {submenuItem.title}
                    </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
            </>
            ))}
        </ul>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebarnav
```

App.JS

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route  } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebarnav from "./components/Sidebarnav";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
   <>
    <Router>
      <Sidebarnav />
      <Routes>
      <Route path='/Home' element={<Home/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: react-router has a link components design for that, why dont you use them?

Comment: Wrap your `li` inside `map()` with `<Link>` and set ``to=`/${menu.title.toLowerCase()}` and make routes for that pages in you `App.js`

Comment: Where are you trying to add any links? What other routes than `"/Home"` are rendered to link to? Please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To create links with react-router-dom you should use `<Link to="yourPath">Your Title</Link>`